# Solve for $x$ where $x=(1-2)(1+2+4)+(2-3)(4+6+9)+(3-4)(9+12+16)+....+(49-50)(2401+2450+2500)$

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following equality:

$$x=(1-2)(1+2+4)+(2-3)(4+6+9)+(3-4)(9+12+16)+....+(49-50)(2401+2450+2500)$$

Solve for $x$.

The only thing I noticed is the first part like $(1-2)$,$(3-4)$ gives us $-1$ but then I just don't see what the trick behind this problem is.

Comment: Hint: Calculate $k^2, k^2+k$ and $(k+1)^2$ for $k=1,2,3,49$.

Comment: The terms are $(m - [m+1])(m^2 + [m^2 + m] + [m+1]^2)$ where $m$ goes from 1 to 49.

Answer (score 2):

Each term is of the form
$$(n-(n+1))(n^2 + (n^2+n) + (n+1)^2) = -(3n^2+3n+1)$$
Hence,
$$x = - \sum_{n=1}^{m} (3n^2+3n+1) = - m(m^2+3m+3)$$
where $m=49$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: have you ever tried to look at a formula like this: $$ {a^3 - b^3 \over a-b} = (?)(?)$$ ? Just expand and observe the two occuring factors and look like the astronomers over long distances ...

***[update]***

As $ {a^3-b^3 \over a - b }= a^2+ab+b^2$ and thus $$  (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) = a^3-b^3 $$the problem-formula is equivalent $(a^3-b^3) + (b^3-c^3) + ... +(x^3-y^3) +  (y^3-z^3) = a^3-z^3 $ and comes out to be $$x = 1^3 - 50^3 = -124999 $$